# Is it possible to edit restored primitive shapes using kineticjs?

Tags: kineticjs

Is it possible to edit restored primitive shapes using kineticjs?

Edit in the sense re-size and destroy restored shapes.
I am using the following kineticjs files
kinetic-v5.0.1.js
kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js

If its possible means help me to find out the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reedited restored rectangle and other shapes in this way

```
var Rectanglenodes = stage.find('Rect');
for (var i = 0; i < Rectanglenodes.length; i++) {
var rect = Rectanglenodes[i];
rect.on("mousedown", function (e) {
var node = e.targetNode;
selectednode = e.targetNode;
selectednodecount = 1;
if (drawingObject == "delete") {
var parentnode = node.parent;
parentnode.destroy();
stage.draw();
}
else if (drawingObject == "clearAll") {
layerText.destroy();
layerLine.destroy();
layerCircle.destroy();
layerrect.destroy();
drawingObject = "";
}
else if (drawingObject == "select") {
select(node);
var children = node.parent.children;
var group = node.parent;
 for (i = 1; i < children.length; i++) {
var str = children[i].getId();
var n = str.length;
var anchorId = str.substring(0, (n - 1));
if (anchorId.toLowerCase().indexOf("rect") >= 0) {
children[i].on('dragmove', function () {
update(this, e);
console.log(this);
layerrect.draw();
});
children[i].on('mousedown touchstart', function () {
group.setDraggable(false);
this.moveToTop();
});
children[i].on('dragend', function () {
group.setDraggable(true);
layerrect.draw();
});
children[i].on('mouseover', function () {
var layer = this.getLayer();
document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
this.setStrokeWidth(4);
layerrect.draw();
});
children[i].on('mouseout', function () {
var layer = this.getLayer();
document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
this.strokeWidth(2);
layerrect.draw();
});
}
}
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, KineticJS primitive shapes can be modified easily even after they've been displayed!

```
// change sizes on various primitive shapes

myCircle.radius(newRadius);

myRect.width(newWidth);

myImage.scale(.75,.75);

// be sure to redraw the layer so the changes are displayed

layer.draw();
```

Comment: Hi markE thanks for your reply,
it is works fine for me too,
my problem is,
a) i stored stage to json like var json = stage.toJSON();
 saved to server and
b) i retrieved json from server and  restore json to stage like 
stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'toImage');

a) re-size and destroy works fine
b) re-size and destroy not working. In both stage drag and drop works fine
Is that anything i need change or add to when saving the stage?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to set `id` property before converting to JSON (also you can use `name` property, see documentation for more information) to each node, that you want to edit.
2. After you have restored stage you can find node by id

   ```
   var node = stage.find('#circle')[0];
   ```
3. Then you can edit node.

Comment: Hi lavrton, thanks for your reply. after restore  layer.on('mousedown', function (e){} event is not firing.

Comment: Do you have any demo? After restore you have to setup listeners again. Because JSON format do not have logic (functions).

Comment: Thank you lavrton i got solution with your help